# Low gpa, but plenty of experience: Neuroscience grad school chances? How can I improve?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, science

I am a Neurobiology, Physiology and Behavior (NPB) undergrad student at UC Davis. I am taking my last year and a half (with 5th year) of classes. I transferred to UC Davis from UC Santa Cruz for my junior year; I completed lower div bio, gen chem, ochem, physics, and calc at UCSC. These are my projected gpa breakdowns:

GPA:
Overall gpa: 3.312 (upward trend)
Overall major gpa: 3.200 (upward trend)
UC Davis major gpa: 3.705 (upward trend)

I am retaking two D+'s, one NPB related the other is not. They were within two quarters and I had a family medical emergency, so I had a rough time. Other than that I have never gotten a D, and got one C- that was also during those bad quarters.

EXPERIENCE: (in process of/completed) 1 first author & 2 coauthor papers:
I have worked in a cognitive neuroscience lab since summer after freshman year at UC Davis, total I will work there for 5 years upon completing my 5th year. I am the coauthor of a paper soon to be published, am in the process of creating an experiment I will be a first author on, and will be a coauthor of another paper my colleague and I are creating.

LETTERS OF REC:
I will have strong letters of rec from both UCSC and UCD. I spent two days a week going to graduate student discussions regarding Alzheimer's at UCSC and was offered a lab position, so two professors there would be options for letters of rec. The doctor I work for at UCD will write me a letter of rec, and I transferred to UCD because of the lab position only, so I'm sure that would be a strong letter of rec.

I'm concerned, because my overall gpa is very low. It didn't click in my head that lower div classes mattered freshman and sophomore year. I am working to get all A's this year, but if I don't, my major gpa will be around a 3.149. I am committed to getting all A's though and made it possible to do so. Ultimate goal is PhD at a top school, but I think I need a master's first to bump my gpa up.

What do you all think? Anything else I can do besides work on grades? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides some schools which have a strict GPA cutoff of 3.5 or something (I don't specifically know of any), don't worry, just apply. Your rec letters and research experience (including published papers) will count for a lot more.

I wouldn't suggest wasting time on a masters at this point from the perspective of neuroscience in the US; if you apply and don't get accepted to a school you want to attend, then you could consider it. I would continue working in labs and as a backup plan try to be hired there over the next year; in my opinion that would be just as useful as a masters if not moreso, especially if you can get yet another publication (your record there is already strong, though, if you can actually complete that first author paper; it sounds like you are only in the beginning stages there).

You can explain health/medical issues contributing to your GPA in one of the many essays you will have to write. You might look almost human on your application.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thank you as a reply, but this was very helpful advice and I'm extremely appreciative! I wanted to go directly into a PhD program, so it's relieving to know I can pursue a research manager position instead of a Masters. Thank you again! You're awesome :)